# AJAX CORS call not working on PHP

Tags: php, ajax, cors

I am trying to make a call to our API server from a simple java-script function. Below is the code that I use:

```
function jack() {
            //fullURL defined here
    debugger;
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var onLoadHandler = function(event) {
      /* do something with the response */
          debugger;
    }
    var onErrorHandler = function(event) {
          /* do something with the response */
              debugger;
        }
    xhr.open('GET',fullURL);
    xhr.onload = onLoadHandler;
    xhr.onerror = onErrorHandler;
    xhr.send();
}
```

I could not load the complete fullURL because the page said: "Your post contains the invalid external" so I can confirm it starts with http and goes to /api/phpInfo.php

I open a browser to this page and start Firebug. In the Firebug console I make a call to jack() and end up in var onErrorHandler = function(event). Firebug is telling me that event is "error" but I need to know what error? If I go to my PHP server I can see in the log that the call was made and a server 200 code was returned?  Firebug also shows that the "HTML" tab returned blank but a call to fullURL does return the info page to me (in a browser)

Help please.

Comment: What is being returned? XML? JSON? Plain text?

Also, is there a reason you aren't using jQuery? It's much much easier

Comment: fullURL is myDomain:myPort/api/phpInfo.php Stackoverflow does not want me to paste the full URL - very frustrating!!

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me!!!
Javascript:

> var httpReq = getXMLHTTPRequest();
>
> function makeCall() {     var myurl =
>   "http://111.111.111.111:11111/api/phpInfo.php";   myRand =
>   parseInt(Math.random()*999999999999999);  var modurl =
>   myurl+"?rand="+myRand;    httpReq.open("GET", modurl, true);
>     httpReq.onreadystatechange = useHttpResponse899;    httpReq.send(); }
>
> function useHttpResponse899() {   if (httpReq.readyState == 4) {
>         if(httpReq.status == 200) {         // do all processings with the
>   obtained values / response here       }   } }

and on the PHP server in phpInfo I had:

```
<?php 
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
phpinfo();  
?>
```